# Displaying Error Messages from a Web Service Call to JSP

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jsp

I am calling a web service to validate an email address. In case of an invalid email address this service returns messages and I need to display them in a JSP. I am using `Jersey` with `Struts2` and I have a form which submits to an action which takes care of this logic at the back end. I am not using a servlet to get the messages from the HttpServletRequest object.

I get a list of messages and I need to display the error message text on the screen but I am not sure how to do it. On click I get the form id which goes to the back end using struts2 action.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend using the Struts2 validation interceptor. The documentation is very straight forward and it's very robust.

https://struts.apache.org/docs/basic-validation.html

https://struts.apache.org/docs/email-validator.html

You simply need to call the interceptor stack in your action in struts.xml, then specify what validations you want. You can then display your error on the JSP should the validation fail.

You can either use the default validators provided by the XML validation or set your own by creating a validate method in the action class that is called by the stack, or both.

http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/struts-2-fielderror-example/

Here is an example for you to work with.